# WordPress, escape CSS attributes values in <head> or inside tags

Tags: css, wordpress, escaping

I am developing a wordpress theme. In the backend, the user has the possibility to modify the design. Example :
[wordpress backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBAtV.jpg)

The values provided by the user are used in the `<head>` tag. Example:

```
<?php function capacity_css_js_in_head() { ?>
    .slide-text{
        color: <?php echo $capacity_slide_text_color ; ?>;
    }
<?php 
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'capacity_css_js_in_head' );
```

how can I correctly escape  $capacity_slide_text_color?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) function to add CSS to the head.

However, no validation or sanitization is included with that function.

"You can use [`wp_kses( $data, array( "\'", '\"' ) );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) or [`wp_strip_all_tags( $data );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_strip_all_tags) or [`esc_html( $data );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html) but this is NOT 100% secure. The actual best way to sanitize custom CSS rules is to use [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/)." -- This is taken directly from the `wp_add_inline_style()` codex page.

Answer (score 0):

```html
just do it 
<?php echo esc_attr($capacity_slide_text_color) ; ?>;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).